# Check if JavaScript class contains static method

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, methods

Is there a way to check if a JavaScript class contains a static method? For example, how to see if the Hello class has the static method "message":

```
class Hello
{
    static get message() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

I am working in NodeJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Hello.hasOwnProperty('message')
```

Answer (score 2):

What your looking for is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

```
var values = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Hello)
// values == ["length", "prototype", "message", "name"]
```

Comment: See also [`Reflect.ownKeys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys)